# Create shared library (.lib and .dll) using qmake and MSVC2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, qmake

I'm porting a shared library from CMake to QMake (for better integration with the rest of our codebase), and am having trouble in Windows with having qmake generate both the .lib and .dll files. 
I have ported this over to Linux and MacOS (easier with Unix shared library formats), but am having trouble with Windows.

Please note that I am not using the Mingw compiler, but the MSVC 2015 compiler. Unfortunately, I can't use the Mingw compiler for various reasons.

Relevant code in my .pro file:

```
Qt -= core gui #not using the qt library
CONFIG += c++14 warn_on
TEMPLATE  = lib
TARGET = MyLibrary
```

With CMake, I was able to set certain .h files as `PUBLIC_HEADER` files, and after running `make install`, it generated the proper .lib and .dll files.

But with qmake, it only generated a very tiny .dll file (<15kb). I tried adding `CONFIG += static` but that created a .lib file with all the symbols there, not the shared library files I am looking for.

Edit: After looking more into it, a better question could be: 
Is there a qmake equivalent (or workaround) of CMake's PUBLIC_HEADER property?

Comment: Under Windows nothing is exported from DLL by default (unlike *nix where all globals are exported from .so). You must have `dllexport` specifier attached to all exported classes while building the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: @Matt is right, you need to take active action in your source code to export classes, functions and other symbols. This is mandatory in Windows, but it is also a recommended practice in Unix. When the MSVC++ compiler sees exported symbols, it automatically creates both the .DLL and the .LIB import library.

To do this in a cross-platform way with qmake, a nice guide is following the pattern of the Qt Creator wizard: Welcome -> New Project -> Library -> C++ library. Project location..., name: 'testlib' (for instance). Next, next, choose your kit, next and finish. The files created by the wizard in the project directory are:

```
testlib.cpp
testlib_global.h
testlib.h
testlib.pro
testlib.pro.user
```

The interesting bits are in testlib.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += TESTLIB_LIBRARY
```

And the header "testlib_global.h"

```
#ifndef TESTLIB_GLOBAL_H
#define TESTLIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(TESTLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define TESTLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define TESTLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // TESTLIB_GLOBAL_H
```

This header should be included in other headers, that would be using the  TESTLIB_EXPORT macro like this (testlib.h):

```
#ifndef TESTLIB_H
#define TESTLIB_H

#include "testlib_global.h"

class TESTLIB_EXPORT Testlib
{
public:
        Testlib();
        // ...
};
```

The key is to define TESTLIB_LIBRARY in the project .pro that builds the library, so the TESTLIB_EXPORT macro is defined as Q_DECL_EXPORT, which in Windows is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)`, and **avoid** defining  TESTLIB_LIBRARY in the projects **using** the library. More about this [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application).

Now, the second part of your question. In [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html), it says:

> PUBLIC_HEADER
>
> Specify public header files in a FRAMEWORK shared library target.
>
> Shared library targets marked with the FRAMEWORK property generate
>   frameworks on macOS, iOS and normal shared libraries on other
>   platforms. This property may be set to a list of header files to be
>   placed in the Headers directory inside the framework folder. On
>   non-Apple platforms these headers may be installed using the
>   PUBLIC_HEADER option to the install(TARGETS) command.

So the PUBLIC_HEADER attribute is only about installing the public headers. To do so in qmake, you need to use INSTALLS in testlib.pro, for instance:

```
unix {
    target.path = /usr/local/lib
    headers.path = /usr/local/include
}
!isEmpty(target.path) {
    INSTALLS += target
}

headers.files = $$HEADERS
!isEmpty(headers.path) {
    INSTALLS += headers
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I tried out your example code and it worked great! Though this is the right way to do it, I had errors with naming classes to be exported that had std classes, which can be fixed using pimpl. In order to avoid a huge refactor, I've decided to do what CMake does internally with their WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS property, which is to generate a file with symbols from all .obj files into a .def file and use the /DEF option when linking. Only a hack until we properly implement what you have described.